# Media PLayer is null in onPause and onResume

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, media-player

I have a media player as global variable and i wanna resume it in onResume and pause it in onPause but both give me nullpointerException. I don't know why it's giving media player as null. I don't thin we need log coz i know the error is nullpointerexception and on the line below mentioned.Here is my code

```
      MediaPlayer md;
      int position;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_show);
        md = new MediaPlayer();
        md.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        md = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tone);
        md.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            md.start();
        }
    });
@Override
    public void onPause(){
       if(md != null ){
       md.pause();
       position = md.getCurrentPosition();
    }
      super.onPause();

}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(md != null){
        md.start();    NullPointerException here
        md.seekTo(position);
    }

}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    if(md != null){
    md.stop();      NullPointerException here
    md.release();
    md = null;}
    super.onStop();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the android app cycle..when ever you press the home button to come out of the app, onStop() is being called along with onPause().

Because of this reason the MediaPlayer gets released every time, so you are receiving that null pointer Exception.

I believe, that you want to stop the music when the app is closed completely, then **replace the onStop() with onDestroy()**...that is the only problem related to null pointer Exception..

Comment: I might also change md.start() into mp.start() [since you are creating a OnPreparedListener..]

Comment: I solved it already but this was it. :D thanks for your time. I learned it by experimenting. :D